# WKHTMLTOPDF on ROR - Create PDF without Displaying It

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I have (with some difficulty) figured out how to generate a PDF file in my Rails app and get the file saved with a single click, but instead of just generating the file, it subsequently opens the html page the PDF is based on.  I would like it to just create the PDF file and NOT display either the html page, nor open the newly created PDF.... Can this be accoplished???

What follows is the code from the controller which fires when the "Print" link is clicked in my app...

```
@approvedbentry = Bentry.find_by_id(b_id)
file_name = @approvedbentry.client.lastnameorbizname + "_" + @approvedbentry.billDate.to_s + "-" + Time.now.strftime("%s") + ".pdf"

respond_to do |format|
  format.html do
    render :pdf => file_name, :template => 'bentries/printbill.html.erb', :wkhtmltopdf => 'S:\Projects\BillSumm\vendor\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe', 
    :format => 'pdf', :save_to_file => Rails.root.join('public\printedbills', file_name),
    :save_only => true
  end
end
```

I thought the "save_only" option would save the file without subsequently displaying anything else, but that is obviously NOT the case.

Can this be done???

TIA